# Carolina Reaper problem

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, peppers, chili

I have a problem on a Carolina Reaper. It's +- 2 months old. I grow them indoors(living room, +- 20 degrees celcius) under a 45 Watt LED grow panel (50 cm above the plants). I use universal potting soil. The PH is 7. After a month I started adding Chili Focus according to the manual (once a week, not too much). I try to water when the soil is getting dry, again, not too much, but enough. I have other Chilli plants under the same conditions and they are doing fine (Carolina Reapers, Jalapenos and Birds Eye). I started looking on the internet and I think it's Bacterial Spot. Am I right?

[image: Sick Carolina Reaper]

update:

- 1 day later I washed away the soil (in the baththub, very carefully not to damage the roots) and replaced it with new soil(1/2 seedling soil, 1/4 potting soil (ph 6), 1/4 perlite and a few cm of hydro granules at the bottom). I also raised the led panel 20 cm higher.
- 10 days later I took some extra photo's:

[image: underneath the leave 1]

[image: underneath the leave 2]

- another 5 days later I took two new photos. If you look close, you see the same condition is still there, but it's hard to say if it's new or it was already there. They remain small, but it does seem to go better. There are new small leaves forming in the top middle and they look better than the ones I removed. I don't know yet what I'll do with them, but for now I am still going to give them a chance. Small question; should I remove the yellow leaves?

[image: after 15 days]

[image: after 15 days]

Comment: Have any other plants started to develop similar conditions? This was posted 9 days ago could you update the picture? Could you hold a leaf up and take a picture of the underside?

Comment: I have 10 plants in total. 4 Reapers, 3 Jalapenos and 3 Bird's eye's. 2 plants have this problem and they are both Reapers. As far as I can see, the other plants are fine. I'll make a picture from the underside of a leave for you this evening; I am at work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked, it does look like bacterial spots:

http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r604100311.html

Regardless, the first thing I would recommend unless you have already done so, is to separate the two plants and quarantine them.

Definitely remove the affected leaves and start over.

Do not use any of the rest of the seeds if you have more, until you are sure.

If nothing helps, or if it starts spreading, discard the plants and start over.

Comment: I thought about quarantaining them, but I only have 1 lamp. They are not touching any other plants and I won't let that happen. It doesn't seem to be spreading. I also noticed, the new (very small) leaves don't seem to have it (yet), so I just removed the affected leaves like you said. If it starts again on the new leaves, I'll quarantaine them.Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Thanks. Please do keep us posted, and best wishes!

Comment: I have no way to be sure this is the right answer, but I have a strong suspicion it indeed is bacterial spot

Comment: Tom, you can always update and let us know if my assumption is wrong. Thanks.